# Spring project returning BeanInstantiationException for cassandraSession, "the local DC must be explicitly set"

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, database-connection, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to set up a Spring Project with Cassandra and Docker.
I have built the docker container and have already tested, if I can add data to the cassandra database. That all works fine.
When it comes to running the application (I use gradle) I get a few errors.

```
*Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource --- Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter).*

*BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession'*
```

So I have a docker-compose.yml file and a application.yml file.

(docker set up)

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mycassandra:
    image: cassandra
    container_name: mycassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
```

(application.yml set up)

```
spring:
    data:
      cassandra:
        port: 9042
        contact-points: mycassandra
        keyspace-name: mykeyspace
        entity-base-package: com.example.springapplication
```

Apart from that I only have one entity with a controller and repo.

I haven't done a lot, so something about the basic set up is missing. Can anyone give me a clue to what I forgot and what the basic set up steps are for a cassandra/spring CRUD application?

Comment: The error explains quite explicitly what is wrong. `Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set `

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses the [Cassandra Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/) to connect to the database. By default, the Java driver is configured to use the `DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy`  which requires that you specify the local data centre name. This is the reason you are getting this error:

```
Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set \
    (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, \
    or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter).*
```

You need to configure the local DC property with:

```
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=dcname
```

In your case, your application YAML should look like:

```
spring:
    data:
      cassandra:
        port: 9042
        contact-points: mycassandra
        local-datacenter: mydcname
        keyspace-name: mykeyspace
        entity-base-package: com.example.springapplication
```

For more info, see [Load Balancing with the Cassandra Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/load_balancing/).

If you're interested, [DataStax has app examples with the full source code on GitHub](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/spring-data-cassandra-dse). Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!